# Limiting and offsetting query result in SMS Content Provider

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am working on a messaging app, I want to limit the number of result from SMS content provider so that I can implement endless scrolling (loading more data on scroll rather than loading the whole conversation at once).

Is there any way to select the top 50 conversations from SMS Content provider, and later to select 50 conversations from a given point ?

```
Cursor cur;
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");

cur = contentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, projection,
    null, null, " date DESC");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `limit 50` in the last argument

```
cur = contentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, projection, null, null, " date DESC limit 50");
```

If you want to get the `i`th "page", meaning offset by `i` times 50 :

```
...," date DESC limit 50 offset "+i);
```

(where I assume `i` is the variable where you hold the index of the chunk you would like to load)

Comment: Thanks Vic, that worked. How can I use it with offset ?

Comment: I have added this precision